# ReactJs component does not get updated/rerendered when the store is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I have this component that shows list of education items added by the user where each time represents where he studied and for how long...etc:

```
class EducationItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const education = !!this.props.profile ? this.props.profile.education : [];
    return (
      <div>
        {!!education &&
          education.map((education_element_data, i) => {
            console.log(
              " ~ file: EducationItems.js ~ line 26 ~ EducationItems ~ education.map ~ i",
              i
            );
            return (
              <EducationItem
                number={i}
                educationElementData={education_element_data}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile.profile,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationItems);
```

It is connected to the `profile` value in the store as you can see:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile.profile,
});
```

When the user adds education, I get the new list of all education(s) he added and I try to updated in the UI. So in the reducer I have this:

> profileReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  profile: null,
};

   case ADD_EDUCATION:
      let updated_profile_with_new_education = state.profile;
      updated_profile_with_new_education.education =
        action.payload.updated_education;
     
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: updated_profile_with_new_education,
      };
```

The problem after the user adds an education successfully, the `EducationItems` component does not get rerendered.

It seems that it is not detecting the change in `store.state.profile.education` for some reason.

I thought that updating anything in `store.state.profile` would get it rerendered since it is connected to that value in the store.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is the double profile in `state.profile.profile` intentional?

Comment: @vl4d1m1r4 no, when I started profileReducer was associate with profile, in ReducersIndex, so if I want to access it I use state.profile. And for the actual profile data, it was stored in profile key in profileReducer. So the result was unintentionnally state.profile.profile if I want to access the profile data.

Comment: Did you see any change in the diff section in the redux dev tools?

Comment: Yes, the change happens correctly in the store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why. But connecting the component to the profileReducer and not the profile element is what solved this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import EducationItem from "./EducationItem";
export class EducationItems extends Component {
  render() {
    const user_profile = this.props.profile.profile;
    console.log(
      " ~ file: EducationItems.js ~ line 7 ~ EducationItems ~ render ~ user_profile",
      user_profile
    );
    const education = !!user_profile ? user_profile.education : [];

    console.log(
      " ~ file: EducationItems.js ~ line 7 ~ EducationItems ~ render ~ education",
      education
    );
    return (
      <div>
        {!!education &&
          education.map((education_element_data, i) => {
            console.log(
              " ~ file: EducationItems.js ~ line 26 ~ EducationItems ~ education.map ~ i",
              i
            );
            return (
              <EducationItem
                number={i}
                educationElementData={education_element_data}
              />
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  // profile: state.profile.profile,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EducationItems);
```

Comment: Ok, now I think I see why the UI was not updating. You are actually mutating the same object in the state. `let updated_profile_with_new_education = state.profile;`. Since the state was only observing this it thinks nothing has changed since you only mutate the education property, but it is the same object and the equality check passes.